# How can I compute the sum of the primes (with powers) that occur in the factorization of an integer?

Tags: nt.number-theory

For example we have $40=2^3⋅5$, so the sum is $S(40)=2^3+5=13$. Similarly, $200=2^3⋅5^2$, so we obtain $S(200)=2^3+5^2=8+25=33$. For a fixed $n$, I'd like to find some properties about $S(n)$. But I could find nothing through google; instead, a lot of people have considered the sum of prime factor without powers

Comment: I think this is off-topic. -- Voted to close.

Answer (score 3):

This is sequence [A008475](http://oeis.org/A008475) at the OEIS. You can find some starting references there.